# How to add intervals to a date in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, datetime

I need to subtract x months from a specific date in python and tried several ways, but get the following errors:

```
dates = np.array(['2023-02-28T00:00:00.000000000','2022-12-31T00:00:00.000000000','2019-01-01T00:00:00.000000000'], dtype=np.datetime64)

dates + np.timedelta64(-5,'M')
numpy.core._exceptions._UFuncInputCastingError: Cannot cast ufunc 'add' input 1 from dtype('<m8[M]') to dtype('<m8[ns]') with casting rule 'same_kind'

dates + relativedelta(months=-5)
numpy.core._exceptions._UFuncBinaryResolutionError: ufunc 'add' cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('O')

datetime.fromtimestamp(dates.astype(datetime) / 1e9) + relativedelta(months=-5)
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: related: [Converting between datetime, Timestamp and datetime64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13703720/10197418)

Answer (score 1):

`relativedelta` is designed to work with python's native `datetime` objects, not `numpy datetime64 object`. Therefore, you should use `datetime` instead of `np.timedelta64` like so:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

t = datetime(2023, 2, 28)
result = t - relativedelta(months=-5)
print(result)


#output

2023-07-28 00:00:00
```

To understand more why np.timedelta cannot work with years and months, look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40290946/16733101)

Comment: conversion from numpy to py datetime is *relatively* straigt-forward, e.g. `datetime.fromtimestamp(t.astype(datetime)/1e9)` for the example in the OP.

Comment: how can the same be doe for an array? I edited the question. and also why does the ```np.timedelta``` not work here?

Comment: @SergeKashlik Please, read this to know why np.timedelta does not work here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40290946/16733101